# Issue exporting function from typescript file

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have this .ts file:

```
let animalTypes: string[] = ["MOOSE","COW","HORSE"];

function getNoise(animalTypes) {

    if (animalTypes === "MOOSE") {console.log("NEIIIIIIIGH whatever noise Moose make");}
    else if (animalTypes === "COW") {console.log("MOOOOOOOOOOO");}
    else if (animalTypes === "HORSE") {console.log("WHINNNNY");}

}

export {getNoise}
```

Which transpiles into this .js file:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var animalTypes = ["MOOSE", "COW", "HORSE"];
exports.animalTypes = animalTypes;
function getNoise(animalTypes) {
    if (animalTypes === "MOOSE") {
        console.log("NEIIIIIIIGH whatever noise Moose make");
    }
    else if (animalTypes === "COW") {
        console.log("MOOOOOOOOOOO");
    }
    else if (animalTypes === "HORSE") {
        console.log("WHINNNNY");
    }
}
exports.getNoise = getNoise;
```

However, I'm receiving this error message when trying to load the .js file and import the functions directly into a  block on my website:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './animals.js' does not
>   provide an export named 'getNoise'

I'm copying an example from class so it's bewildering that it isn't working but there we have it.

Does anyone know what might be causing this SyntaxError?

Here is the relevant html, too:

```
import {getNoise, animalTypes} from "./animals.js";
document.getElementById("target").onclick = function() {
      getNoise(animalTypes[1]);
}
```

Comment: Just use `export getNoise`

Comment: What module loader are you using to load JavaScript modules into the HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are loading modules into the HTML file using the ECMA6 module loader and compiling your TypeScript into CommonJS modules.

Those two module systems are not compatible.

Try changing your tsconfig.json file so that it builds ECMA6 modules instead.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
  },
}
```

Your HTML file would then look like this:

```
<script type="module">
    import { getNoise, animalTypes } from "./animals.js";
    const noise = getNoise(animalTypes[1]);
    console.log(noise);
</script>
```

Here is [a demo for your on GitHub.](https://github.com/shaunluttin/typescript-html-es6-module-imports) Note also that you need to export `animalTypes` in addition to `getNoise` like this:

```
export {
  animalTypes,
  getNoise
}
```

Comment: Does the tsconfig.json file go in the same directory as where I'm running the tsc command to compile?

Comment: I did get it to work, actually but just by changing my .js file such that instead of doing exports.getNoise = getNoise, I did export {getNoise}. What is the different between those? 

I'll mark yours as the answer because looking at your repo helped me. Thanks!

Comment: You asked, "What is the different between those?" The answer is that those are two different module export styles. Module export styles include AMD, CommonJS, ES6, UMD, and SystemJS. See also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#code-generation-for-modules